# How to express fmod() function or periodic functions in maths

Tags: periodic-functions

I have a periodic function with `fmod()` like this (in C):

```
float f(float x) {
    x = fmod(x, 1);
    if (x < 0.5f) return 1 - x;
    else return x
}
```

If I need a formal math formula for this function, what is the prettiest way?

Do people use `fmod` or `mod` functions in formulas like this? It looks strange.

$$
f(x) = 
\left\{ 
             \begin{array}{**lr**}  
             1-\mathrm{fmod} (x,1), & 0 \leq \mathrm{fmod} (x,1) < 0.5  \\  
             \mathrm{fmod}(x,1), & 0.5 \leq \mathrm{fmod} (x,1) < 1
             \end{array}  
\right.
$$

Comment: If you can solve for $\text{fmod}(x,1)=0,0.5,1$ then you can change the expression. (Even if there is a solution, the expression may not be so 'pretty' as you wish). Otherwise, it's impossible to re-express the equation.

Comment: Thanks. Actually `fmod()` is the real number version of 'divide and find remainder' operation. So `fmod(x, c)` produces periodic effect with cycle c. I wonder if there's a way to express this operation. (I don't know if mathematicians use $n \ \rm{mod} \ m$ for integers)

Comment: Ah, I see. How about $f(x)=\max\{\lfloor x\rfloor,1-\lfloor x\rfloor\}$?

Comment: @EricMonlye Actually, you want $\max\{x-\lfloor x\rfloor,\lceil x\rceil -x\}$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen You are right. I mistook the $\lfloor\rfloor$ for the decimal part.

Comment: That being said, $x\bmod 1$ for `fmod(x,1)` is certainly understood.